# Background colour div with background image

Tags: css, background-image

I want to create a small white div/background at the top of this site. 
http://bit.ly/ZgawU6

The front page shows it correctly, however I've made this with a background-image. When the same background image is used on a page like this: it's at 50% or something, and top:0 won't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

http://bit.ly/1311wSB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was wrap the div with the class of navigation container with another wrapper div, lets call it outer-navigation-wrapper then applied this css.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-navigation-wrapper">
    <div class="container navigation-container">
    ...
    </div> <!-- end navigation-container -->
</div> <!-- end outer-navigation-wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
.outer-navigation-wrapper {
   background: #fff;
   height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked a treat.